# How to Convert Amount( Lakh for eg. 1,02,754) in Words in Crystal report..?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I want to convert amount(Lakh for eg. 1,02,754) in words....

```
if UpperCase(left(ToWords(ToNumber(RIGHT(CSTR({vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.InvoiceTotal}),2))),len(ToWords(ToNumber(RIGHT(CSTR({vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.InvoiceTotal}),2))))-12)) ="ZERO" then
{vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.Currency}&" . "& UPPERCASE(TOWORDS(102754,0))&" ONLY"
else
{vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.Currency}&" . "&(Split(UPPERCASE(TOWORDS({vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.InvoiceTotal}))," AND"))[1]+ " AND POINT " + UpperCase(left(ToWords(ToNumber(RIGHT(CSTR({vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.InvoiceTotal}),2))),len(ToWords(ToNumber(RIGHT(CSTR({vwDSRAirInvoiceReport.InvoiceTotal}),2))))-12)) + " ONLY "
```

Comment: You should really have proper examples what kind of words you want in different kind of cases, especially if it's something that is used in only small portion of the world like Indian numbering system.

Comment: @pankaj, where you want this conversion in crystal report or sqlserver or in C#? you question heading and tag are mismatch

Answer (score 0):

**There is a multiple way to populate it. Its depend to you.
Please try for Indian currency.**

numbervar RmVal:=0;
numbervar Amt:=0; 
numbervar pAmt:=0; 
stringvar InWords :="";
 
Amt := Round({@Total Amount},0); 
if Amt > 10000000 then RmVal := truncate(Amt/10000000); 
if Amt = 10000000 then RmVal := 1; 
if RmVal = 1 then 
InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " crore" 
else 
if RmVal > 1 then InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " crores";

Amt := Amt - Rmval * 10000000; 
if Amt > 100000 then RmVal := truncate(Amt/100000); 
if Amt = 100000 then RmVal := 1; 
if Amt = 0 then RmVal := 0;
if RmVal >= 1 then 
InWords := InWords + " " + towords(RmVal,0) + " lakhs";

Amt := Amt - Rmval * 100000; 
if Amt > 0 then InWords := InWords + " " + towords(truncate(Amt),0); 
pAmt := (Amt - truncate(Amt)) * 100; 
if pAmt > 0 then 
InWords := InWords + " and " + towords(pAmt,0) + " paisa only" 
else 
InWords := InWords + " only"; 
UPPERCASE(InWords)

Comment: please add your though in a example and direct link use with more explanation. So only direct link is not suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Number to words in Crystal formula:

```
ProperCase(ToWords(800000, 0) )
```

or

```
Stringvar str := "1,102,754";
ProperCase( ToWords(Int(tonumber(str)), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get comma separated string from SQL and just pass to crystal report

`select CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(salary AS money), 1)`